# Distinct Json Data c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

i have created a method in asp.net core to get the parent name and its childs name in a single json array but i dont know how to do it what my method is giving me result is following

```
{
      "parent": "Kitchen & Dining ",
    "parentID": "QojQhZoUTkG1VhOMJVOBmw==",
    "child": "Bakeware",
    "childID": "BamlddxbUk2lx3uhaT4Hbg=="
},
{
      "parent": "Hobbies",
    "parentID": "yTCm3n8OCUSDQBzDt1f9Hw==",
    "child": "Travel",
    "childID": "CAqwuhPIL02T2ufP/Tl0CA=="
},
{
      "parent": "Kitchen & Dining ",
    "parentID": "QojQhZoUTkG1VhOMJVOBmw==",
    "child": "Table Linen",
    "childID": "EMz9RMY4RESyKtvFVAJTVQ=="
},
{
      "parent": "Kitchen & Dining ",
    "parentID": "QojQhZoUTkG1VhOMJVOBmw==",
    "child": "Tools and Gadgets",
    "childID": "FQtZRfDqtkGrn2II8HobZw=="
},
{
      "parent": "Kitchen & Dining ",
    "parentID": "QojQhZoUTkG1VhOMJVOBmw==",
    "child": "Dinnerware",
    "childID": "FXmgG6wf9UW9AC519gHuTw=="
},
{
      "parent": "Hobbies",
    "parentID": "yTCm3n8OCUSDQBzDt1f9Hw==",
    "child": "Camping & Trecking",
    "childID": "Kgj+Y1xdiUO2i79hxyDE6w=="
};
```

but i dont want data like this I want it like this :

```
{
      "parent": "Kitchen & Dining ",
    "parentID": "QojQhZoUTkG1VhOMJVOBmw==",
    "ChildData": [
      {
  "child": "Travel",
    "childID": "CAqwuhPIL02T2ufP/Tl0CA=="
  },
   {
  "child": "Table Linen",
    "childID": "EMz9RMY4RESyKtvFVAJTVQ"
  },
   {
  "child": "Tools and Gadgets",
    "childID": "FQtZRfDqtkGrn2II8HobZw=="
  }
  ]
},
{
      "parent": "Hobbies",
    "parentID": "yTCm3n8OCUSDQBzDt1f9Hw==",
    "ChildData":[
{"child": "Travel",
    "childID": "CAqwuhPIL02T2ufP/Tl0CA=="},
{"child": "Camping & Trecking",
    "childID": "Kgj+Y1xdiUO2i79hxyDE6w=="}
 ]
}
```

how can i do it. I am using following method to get the result from mysql in c# asp.net core

```
var data = await (from p in _db.ProductCategoryRelationship
                    join s in _db.Products
                    on p.ProductId equals s.Id
                    where p.CategroyId == id
                    select s).ToListAsync();
```

is there a way to tweak this method to get the required result or to create another method that can give me my result

Comment: that code on its own doesn't produce JSON. Where are you making it into JSON? You can't really produce a hierarchical structure like that using SQL, so you'll have to do some sort of transformation on it as a secondary operation.

Comment: i think he means when he return the data to the client, he convert it to json, @Hasan Rasheed am i right ?

Comment: you can iterate through the result and create your customized json and then return it to client

Comment: Yes when i am sending it to client i convert it to json @Mohammed Fahmawi  and i have thought about itrateing but i dont know how to make required result

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:  I haven't worked with `asp.net-core`, so I'm just assuming regular `LINQ` is available in that environment.  I am also doing this from memory.

Assuming you have a way to convert your data into JSON that you haven't shown us, it looks like you have a basic data transformation problem.  You need to convert one data structure to another.

And that is where LINQ comes in very handy.

```
// Group by the parent information, so the output is a sequence of 
// collection records with a Key property (what you grouped on).

data2 = data.GroupBy(d => new { parent = d.parent, parentID = d.parentID})

// You can now create an anonymous type that has the parent information
// (as sub-fields in the Key property) and a collection of child
// records.

            .Select(g => new { parent = g.Key.parent,
                               parentID = g.Key.parentID,
                               ChildData = 
                                   g.Select(r => new { r.child,
                                                       r.childID }).ToArray()
                             });
```

You might want to create a named type that follows this structure (rather than the anonymous type I used), and create it in your LINQ instead (rather than `new`-ing up an anonymous type).

```
class ParentType {
    string parent { get;set;}
    string parentID { get;set; }
    ChildType[] ChildData { get;set; }
}
class ChildType {
    string child { get;set; }
    string childID { get;set }
}
```

Then the `Select` `LINQ` clause would look like this:

```
.Select(g => new ParentType() {
                   parent = g.Key.parent,
                   parentID = g.Key.parentID,
                   ChildData = g.Select( r => new ChildType() {
                          child = r.child,
                          childID = r.childID }).ToArray()
                })
.ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. Asp.net core by default have output formatters that convert data to JSON when sending it to client

Comment: And Your answer will give me the required input but it will repeat the parent names I don't want parent name to repeat I want one Parent Name and all its child data to come inside ChildData Tag as i have shown in the question

Comment: Is that based on reading what I wrote, or trying the code?  My code should produce one record per parent and all the children inside the ChildData tag.  However, if that's not what you're getting, I apologize.